# VS2019 and ReSharper theme issue

Tags: themes, resharper

I use vs 2019 and ReSharper 2020. My VS theme is a One Dark Pro.  I always have this problem when using dark themes. When I use Debug mode, it shows ReSharper values at the end of lines. But because the colors are not compatible with the theme, they are not readable and blend into each other. How can I change this feature?

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwmco.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Fonts and Colors`->`ReSharper Debugger DataTip` - change these colours what you would like. The majority of ReSharper's colours can be adjusted here.

[image]